# Semicolon in object variable name

Tags: ruby, ldap

There's a common LDAP attribute called userCertificate;binary.  It actually has a semi-colon in the attribute name.  In ruby, I turn an LDAP entry into a OpenStruct object called 'struct'.

```
>> struct.class
=> OpenStruct
```

But of course ruby thinks it's an end-of-line character.

```
?> struct.userCertificate;binary
NameError: undefined local variable or method `binary' for main:Object
        from (irb):52
        from :0
```

IRB knows that the local variable is there, because it gives me `struct.userCertificate;binary` from the tab auto-completion.  I can also see the class variable when calling struct.methods on it.

```
>> struct.methods
=> ... "send", "methods", "userCertificate;binary=", "hash", ...
```

It's definitely there, I can see the contents if I print the whole variable to_s().  But how can I access the local variable when it has a semicolon in it?  I have workarounds for this but I thought it was an interesting problem to post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Syntactically, I think there is no way around the fact that a semicolon terminates the statement, so I can't imagine there is a way to do exactly what you'd like.  However, you could use the `send` method to retrieve the value:

```
>> struct.send('userCertificate;binary')
```

Assigning to such a member would be similar:

```
>> struct.send('userCertificate;binary=', my_binary_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused. You are asking about how to access a local variable, but your code examples are about methods?

If it's a local variable, then I don't know any way to access it. However, if it is anything *but* a local variable, then you can use the appropriate reflection method to get access to it: `Module#const_get` for constants, `Object#instance_variable_get` for instance variables, `Object#send` for methods and so on.